# jQuery unrecognized expression: input:checked[type=radio]

Tags: jquery

Hello I am quite new at coding and I'm running into an error.
I get the following error from this code:

```
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input:checked[type=radio][name=ASMTQUESTION:]
```

This is the code:

```
var input = $$('#ASMTQUESTION\\:' + childId);
    if (input.length > 1 || input.length == 0) {
        input = $$('input:checked[type=radio][name=ASMTQUESTION:' + childId + ']');}
```

Please let me know what the error is.

Comment: why you have 2 $ ?

Comment: and the  `:checked` need to be at the end

Comment: That is what the programmer before me included, I have already deleted the doubles so that I am left with single $'s but that doesn't solve the error.

Comment: try you program with simple selector like `$(input[type=radio])` then add the other one by one and you will find the issue

Comment: Thanks! Putting the :checked at the end solved it!

Answer (score -1):

Attributes selector should have their values between quotes, for instance:

```
input:checked[type="radio"]
```